# Could not open connection to authentication agent even though SSH_AUTH_SOCK defined

Tags: bash, ssh, ubuntu-12.04, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

First I start the ssh-agent with

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

I confirm that `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set by running `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, which encouragingly returns `/tmp/ssh-oCsFfHvR3345/agent.3345`.

Yet when I run `sudo ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, I get

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Moreover, `ssd-add -l` returns `The agent has no identities.`

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` for that? You want to run that as your normal user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running SSH commands through `sudo` the environment variables won't be set.

From `man sudoers`:

> By default, the env_reset option is enabled.  This causes commands to be executed with a new, minimal environment.  On AIX (and Linux systems without PAM), the environment is initialized with the contents of the /etc/environment file.  The new environment contains the TERM, PATH, HOME, MAIL, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER, USERNAME and SUDO_* variables in addition to variables from the invoking process permitted by the env_check and env_keep options.  This is effectively a whitelist for environment variables.

You can check which environment variables are available to your sudo commands by running `sudo env`.

The above would explain the behaviour you describe but you really should be running `ssh` commands as a **regular (non-super) user**.